# Problems with json file (Python)

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with this json file : [Zips.json](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json)! .

I Didnt find a way to count the number of postal codes in each state. I tried many ways such as this :

```
file=open("C:\Users\Alex\Downloads/zips.json","r")
lines=json.loads(file.readline())
number=0
states=lines["state"]
for line in file:
    lines=json.loads(line)
    if lines ["state"]==states:
        number=number+1
    else:
        print u"states:",states, u"Number of codes: ",number
        states=lines["state"]
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, i add number=0 under my else but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `collections.Counter`:

```
import json
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

counter = None
state_getter = itemgetter('state')

with open('zips.json') as fh:
    zips_data = (json.loads(line) for line in fh)
    states_names = map(itemgetter('state'), zips_data)
    counter = Counter(states_names)

print(counter)
```